# shooting bullet in a platform game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to make a platform game where the player can shoot a ball.

Weirdly my code seems to shoot the bullet, but I can't figure out why it's not shooting from my player.

It's been hours and I still don't understand what is the problem.

Here's the problem :

[URL=http://fr.tinypic.com/r/i5ry1i/8]My Video[/URL]
Images : 
[image]
[image]

Here's my code :

In my Main.as

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
private var bulletList:Array = new Array();

public function keyDownFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
...
.
} else if (event.keyCode == 70) {
                fireBullet();}
..
}

public function fireBullet():void
{

    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(hero.mc.x, hero.mc.y, playerDirection);
    addChild(bullet);
    trace("addChild Bullet");

    bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved);
    bulletList.push(bullet);

}
```

In my Bullet.as :

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.Stage;

    public class Bullet extends MovieClip {

        private var speed:int = 30;
        private var initialX:int;

        public function Bullet(heroX:int, heroY:int, playerDirection:String) {
            trace("bullet called");
            trace(heroY);
            trace(heroX);
            // constructor code
            if(playerDirection == "left") {
                speed = -30; //speed is faster if player is running
                x = heroX - 25;
            } else if(playerDirection == "right") {
                speed = 30;
                x = heroX + 25
            }
            y = heroY;

            initialX = x; //use this to remember the initial spawn point

        }
```

Do you know what could be the problem in my code ?

Thank you very much for your help.

---

**EDIT**

Here's the change I've made :

In my Main.as

```
public function fireBullet():void
{
    var heroP:Point = new Point(hero.mc.x, hero.mc.y);
    heroP = localToLocal(hero.mc, this, heroP);
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(heroP.x, heroP.y, playerDirection);
    addChild(bullet);
    trace("addChild Bullet");

    bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved);
    bulletList.push(bullet);

}
public function localToLocal(from:DisplayObject, to:DisplayObject, origin:Point):Point
{
    if (!to || !from) return new Point();

    return to.globalToLocal(from.localToGlobal(origin));
}
```

I've made no change in my Bullet.as

---

**2nd EDIT**

I've put some "trace" in order to understand what is happening, and I must say that I don't understand at all !
The bullet is still not aligned !

In my Main.as I've put "`trace(hero.mc.y)`" in the fireBullet

```
        public function fireBullet():void
{
    var heroP:Point = new Point(hero.mc.x, hero.mc.y);
    var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(heroP.x, heroP.y, playerDirection);
    heroP = localToLocal(hero.mc, this, heroP);
    addChild(bullet);


    trace(hero.mc.y);


    trace("addChild Bullet");
    bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved);
    bulletList.push(bullet);
}
```

In my Bullet.as I've put "trace(heroPXY)".

```
public function Bullet(heroPX:int, heroPXY:int, playerDirection:String) {
            trace("bullet called");
            // constructor code
            if(playerDirection == "left") {
                speed = -30; //speed is faster if player is running
                x =  heroPX;
            } else if(playerDirection == "right") {
                speed = 30;
                x =  heroPX;
            }
            y = heroPXY;


            trace(heroPXY);



            initialX = x; //use this to remember the initial spawn point
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
        }
```

**The result for trace(heroPXY) and trace(hero.mc.y) are exactly the same ! So why the bullet is not aligned ??**

Comment: check the clip for the bullet, maybe it is not done correctly e.g. offest by some values?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to convert coordinate space e.g. by using following function:

```
/**
 * <p>converts coordinates of clip "from" to coordinate space of "to" clip</p>
 * @param   from
 * @param   to
 * @param   origin
 * @return
 */
public function localToLocal(from:DisplayObject, to:DisplayObject, origin:Point):Point
{
    if (!to || !from) return new Point();

    return to.globalToLocal(from.localToGlobal(origin));
}
```

Usage:

```
var heroP:Point = new Point(hero.mc.x, hero.mc.y);
heroP = localToLocal(here.mc, this, heroP);
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(heroP.x, heroP.y, playerDirection);
    addChild(bullet);
```

This should convert hereo's mc coordinate space into the coordinate space of `this` where you add this bullet.

Comment: Hmm If I put trace(hero.mc.x) in the fireBullet function, the result is : 69.2. and if I put trace(heroP.x), the result is 211.95. So heroP.x is not equal to hero.mc.x ... Any idea why ?

Comment: It seems that, when the hero is above y= 160, the bullet is well aligned with the player. when the hero y below y = 160, the bullet is not aligned.